# Unity3D 2020 - VSCode - What happened to intellisense?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Overnight, any help I had for Unity3D in VSCode, i.e. intellisense, disappeared. And I get the sense, no pun intended, that I'm not the only one who's afflicted.

I've tried updating and reinstalling what I assumed VSCode needed to make Unity3D intellisense work.  And have checked and re-checked settings, reinstalled VSCode package, in Unity3D.

I've worked through a few tutorials that claimed to address the issue.

What else does VSCode depend on to make this relationship work?

Thanks! Here's to hoping you've fixed this and your life has gotten easier!

Comment: Not seen this myself but maybe some of these solutions from January might work for you: https://forum.unity.com/threads/intellisense-not-working-for-visual-studio-code.812040/ I'd also consider posting directly on the unity forums

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Edit > Preferences > External Tools > Regenerate Project Files (This is because of a bug where the VS Code extension doesn't generate the project files correctly the first time, you can check it out [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/intellisense-doesnt-provide-its-features-when-editing-a-script-with-visual-studio-code)).

You'll need to be using the VS Code Editor Extension 1.2.0 (you can check which version you're using in the package manager) or later for that option to appear. Also if for whatever reason there are 2 .sln files in your project folder (I've had that happen before, though it's less likely), that also causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First, thanks to Lightning_A and Charleh!

The resolution to my specific circumstance was to install the VSCode extension "Unity Snippets Modified" https://github.com/with-heart/vscode-unity-snippets

I had been using https://github.com/kleber-swf/vscode-unity-code-snippets.

Perhaps it's just a matter of Kleber's extension, which is/was great, was broken upon updating Unity to 2020?  I dunno and don't have the time to look into it, unfortunately.

Hopefully, my question, the answers I received, and my subsequent resolution saves others from the rabbit-hole I went down.

Again, thanks everyone!

Comment: Nice question/answer. While I think the best up-to-date solution is "Don't use snippets from GitHub". Since people _probably_ get lazy/busy in the future to sync. up with the upstream.